# Unlimited line length Sublime 3

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

How make maximum length of line in Sublime 3 unlimited?
I've tried to add `"max_line_length": null`, or even `"max_line_length": 10000"` to Preferences.sublime-setting, but it not works for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just uncheck **wordwrap** flag in **View** menu.